# How to get url without query string like stackoverflow in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, url-rewriting, url-mapping

I have a jsp page, which url is:

> http://localhost:8084/WebApplication1/newjsp.jsp

There is an anchor tag in it:

> a href="MobileArticles?name=abcde"

web.xml specification:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MobileArticlesLinkerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MobileArticles</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is the code for doGet in the servlet:
    `String respuesta = "Article_template.jsp";
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(respuesta);
    rd.forward(request, response);`

It is getting redirected to a jsp page "Article_template.jsp".

The process is fine. But I need a different URL pattern for this page:

Current URL pattern: "http://localhost:8084/WebApplication1/MobileArticles?name=abcde"

And I want it like:
"http://localhost:8084/WebApplication1/MobileArticles/abcde"

Please help me how I can achieve this?

Comment: I tried adding /MobileArticles/* in url-pattern. But it is causing infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found out one solution for it.

It may not be the correct way but it works for me.

The trick is:

1. Servlet is not involved at all
2. Set a url-pattern for your jsp page in web.xml

   `<servlet>
       <servlet-name>ArticleTemplate</servlet-name>
       <jsp-file>/Article_template.jsp</jsp-file>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>ArticleTemplate</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/ArticleTemplate/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>`
3. We have to call the JSP page directly from the anchor tag

   `<a href="ArticleTemplate/abcde">Article Link</a>`
4. Finally at the JSP page, we have to use scriptlets to access the java classes and fetch the data from the database.

   `<%
   ----- Your code -----
   %>`